# How to increment key values of dict by 1 inside a list of dictionaries?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries. I want to get top 5 query based on how many times the particular query is entered by the user. How can I do this ?

The below is my approach for this problem but this way I am not being able to solve the problem.

```
def get_top_5_query():
    my_list = [{'query': 'one'}, {'query': 'two.'}, {'query': 'three'}...]
    q = input("Enter query:") # this will be one, two etc(key query value)
    q_count = 0
    new_list = []
    if q in list:
      q_count += 1
    # now increment matched query count by 1:
    # for example
      #if q is 'one' then list should be
       # [{'query': 'one', count:1}]
       

def main():
    choice = "y"
    while choice == "y":
        get_top_5_query()
        choice = input("Enter 'y' if Yes and 'n' if No(y/n) : ").lower()
        if choice == "n":
            print("Bye!!")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: "it does not work" tells us nothing, if it did you wouldn't be posting... What exactly doesn't work? [ask] [mre]

Comment: @Julien actually there's a comment in the code too and also i have edited my question please check it now ?

Comment: What does your ```get_top_5_query``` return or print ?

Comment: @Ram it should print sorted list with count

Comment: Sorted by what ? @D_P

Comment: @Ram sort by mostly entered query by user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of a list of dictionaries like this - `[{'query': 'one'}, {'query': 'two.'}, {'query': 'three'}...]` You could just create a dictionary like this - `{'one': 0, 'two': 0, 'three': 0...}`
where `'one'`, `'two'` etc., are `queries` and `0`'s are `counts`.

```
def get_top_5_query(my_list):
    q = input("Enter query:") # this will be one, two etc(key query value)
    if q in my_list:
      my_list[q] += 1
    
       
def main():
    choice = "y"
    my_list = {'one': 0, 'two': 0, 'three': 0}
    while True:
        choice = input("Enter 'y' if Yes and 'n' if No(y/n) : ").lower()
        if choice == "n":
            print("Bye!!")
            break
        else:
            get_top_5_query(my_list)
    print(list(dict(sorted(my_list.items(), key=lambda x: -x[1])).keys()))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This prints the `my_list` sorted by the `count` in descending order.

Sample output looks like this:

> `['two', 'three', 'one']`

Comment: Currently `my_list = {'one': 0, 'two': 0, 'three': 0}` this is a dictionary but I need this as a list . When using list `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'

Comment: Since we changed a list to a dictionary, You need to make changes in your code accordingly. You could post where you are getting this error so that I can help.

Comment: Ok I will manage this but is there a way so that I can print only list of tuple keys(not with values) instead of list of tuples ?

Comment: I want to print sorted list without values like this `['two', 'one', 'three']` instead of `[('two', 2), ('one', 0), ('three', 0)]`

Comment: Updated answer. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

Do something like follow:-

```
my_list = [{'query': 'one'}, {'query': 'two'}, {'query': 'three'}]
def get_top_5_query():
    global my_list
    q = input("Enter query:") # this will be one, two etc(key query value)
    for i in my_list:
        if q in i.values():
            if 'count' in i:
                i['count']+=1
            else:
                i['count']=1

       

def main():
    choice = "y"
    while choice == "y":
        get_top_5_query()
        choice = input("Enter 'y' if Yes and 'n' if No(y/n) : ").lower()
        if choice == "n":
            print("Bye!!")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: it doesn't increment count by 1 if I again run the function with choice `n` ?

Comment: when you give the input ```n``` the function will not be called and value will not incremented.

Comment: see your main function where you are  calling the get_top_5_query function.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```
def get_top_5_query(new_dict):
    my_list = [{'query': 'one'}, {'query': 'two.'}, {'query': 'three'}]
    query = input("Enter query:") 
    if query in new_dict.keys():
        new_dict[query] += 1
    else:
        new_dict[query] = 1
    return new_dict       

def main():
    result_dict = {}
    choice = "y"
    while choice == "y":
        result_dict = get_top_5_query(result_dict)
        choice = input("Enter 'y' if Yes and 'n' if No(y/n) : ").lower()
        if choice == "n":
            print("Bye!!")
    
    print(sorted(result_dict.items(), key=lambda q: q[1], reverse=True))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This is what the response looks like

```
[('two', 2), ('one', 1), ('three', 1)]
```